# form comes with pre filled data which i cant see how?

Tags: php, html, cakephp

I am using cakephp for a website. A username and password appears on the form prefilled. This is not hardcoded into the login form or appears in any controller. How does this happen? I have no idea how this happens

```php
<?= $this->Form->create('User') ?>
<?= $this->Form->input('username',['label'=>'Username']) ?>
<?= $this->Form->input('password',['label'=>'Password', 'type' =>'password']) ?>
<?= $this->Form->button(__('Login')) ?>
<?= $this->Html->link(' Forgot Password', array('action' => 'forgotPassword1')) ?>
<?= $this->Form->end() ?>
```

http://andrewt.com.au/crm/users/login

Comment: The form helper will pick up values in the current request object, so check whether there's something present (`debug($this->request->data)`), your app might inject them somewhere. ps, please always mention your exact CakePHP version (last line in `lib/Cake/VERSION.txt` or `vendor/cakephp/cakephp/VERSION.txt`)

Comment: the version  is 3.2

Comment: there is no output for debug($this->request->data)

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "_no output_"? No output at all? Or an empty array?

Comment: I just get an empty array

Comment: And where exactly did you put that debug snippet? Right the line before the `$this->Form->create()` call? If not, put it there.

Comment: debug($this->request);
                    ?>
                </div>
                <?= $this->Form->create('User') ?>

Comment: Does `debug($this->Form->getSourceValue('username'))` return anything? Check it _before **and** after_ the `$this->Form->create('User')` call. btw, passing a string to `FormHelper::create()` is deprecated, a string is not a valid context in the default configuration. I'd also suggest searching the whole codebase for the string `username`, to figure where it might get set so that the form helper picks it up.

Comment: That is browser form input cache

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The layout held this username which was hard to even see on this file.